# Rails turn feature on/off on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, real-time

I am a newbie to rails.  I have used feature flags when i was in java world.  I found that there are a few gems in rails (rollout and others) for doing it.  But how to turn a feature on/off on the fly in rails.

In java we can use a mbean to turn features on the fly.  Any idea or pointers on how to do this? I dont want to do a server restart on my machines once a code is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a way of communicating to all your processes at once, which is non-standard, then you'd need some kind of centralized configuration system. [Redis](http://redis.io/) is a really fast key-value store which works well for this, but a database can also do the job if a few milliseconds per page load to figure out which features to enable isn't a big deal.

If you're only deploying on a single server, you could also use a static YAML or JSON configuration file that's read before each request is processed. The overhead of this is almost immeasurable.

Comment: does this mean we have to use a redis like store (or) common json files for all such config settings?

Comment: You need some kind of inter-process communication channel, a common store of some sort. There's a lot of options here, so it's best to choose something you're familiar with, comfortable with, and have confidence it's reliable enough for what you're doing.